# How to do iteration in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why would the code below produce an output of 5? And what does it mean for the condition while n? Shouldn't it always produce an infinite loop since n will always be true?

```
n = 10000
count = 0

while n:
    count = count + 1
    n = n / 10
    n = int(n)

print (count)
```

Output: 5

Comment: `n = 0` makes `while n:` end, so no, `n` is not always true.

Comment: Why not work out on paper what happens? What do you think `n = n / 10` does each iteration?

Comment: @Mark_M Look at the line after. What happens when you take a decimal number less than 1 and call `int` on it. `int(0.1)` -> `0`.

Comment: Not enough coffee yet. Sorry.

Comment: @Mark_M I'm pretty sure since my Python Shell shows ver. 3.6.1

Comment: Sorry Colin - I read past the int(n) line. The answers below are right. Not sure why they are getting downvoted.

Comment: why not printing the value at each iteration instead of posting here?

Answer (score 1):

No "n" will not always be true. Let's see it step by step, I'm going to draw a table below, in each step n will be divided by 10 and count will increase by 1

```
n        isConditionTrue    count
10000    yes                1
1000     yes                2
100      yes                3
10       yes                4
1        yes                5
0        no                 5
```

So, now loop will break and print(count) will produce 5

Answer (score 0):

`while n` is a shorthand for `while n != 0`, or, more precisely, `while n == True`. The code will output 5 because `n` is 5 digits long. Each time through the loop, you lose a digit of `n` (`n = n / 10` then `n = int(n)`) until `n` becomes zero.

Comment: When is a positive number divided by 10 ever zero? The tag says python 3 which does float division by default.

Comment: @Mark_M, it's converted to integer afterwards

Comment: Oh geez. Sorry.

Comment: Actually n does not become exactly zero after 5 iterations but it becomes that small that int(n) represents it as 0

Comment: @SamChats Oh cool. I deleted my comment because seemed a bit too nit picky.

Answer (score 0):

`while n:` means `while n != 0:`. Output is `5` because of you initialize `n = 10000` which is `5` digits long.  And in each step `n` will be divided by `10` and count will increase by `1`. While `n == 0` the loop condition will `False` and will terminate it.

```
>>> n = 10000
>>> count = 0
>>> while n:
...     count = count + 1
...     n = n/10
...     n = int(n)
...     print(n)
... 
1000
100
10
1
0
>>> print(count)
5
>>>
```